# Server Error: 'The user does not exist or is not unique'

Tags: error

Many lists on the our sites are giving a server error screen (attached). However right now again they are working fine. Please check the screenshots below.

I was getting a similar error on the Navigation page (from the Settings menu) but we could not recreate the error later and so we could not do anything. It looks like the error is popping up randomly. Our SP2010 environment is not new.

Any help is appreciated!

[image: Error]

Comment: Is this happens for all users?

Comment: No, only some users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is related to permission problems for specific users in the Active Directory. These users may have restricted access to the SharePoint site or their user information are cached in the WSS_Content database.

These are two solutions you can start from for solving your problem:

1- [Restricted access](http://mrhodes.net/2009/10/28/the-user-does-not-exist-or-is-not-unique-8/).
2- [Caching problem](http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2009/12/14/the-user-does-not-exist-or-is-not-unique/).

Comment: I am on FBA using Claim Based.